# R incrementation - avoiding looping

Tags: r, loops

My data look like this. 
Each `id` has been observed several time. 
`main` is the result of each observation.

What I need to do is to increment each time the `main` has changed, so each time the result of observation is different from the previous one.

So for example, `id` the first observation result is `20` then `30` then a succession of `12`.

```
> dtd
  id main ep
1   1   20  1
2   1   30  1
3   1   12  1
4   1   12  1
5   1   12  1
6   1   15  1
7   1   15  1
8   2   30  1
9   2   12  1
10  2   12  1
11  2   23  1
12  2   23  1
```

What I need in the end is this

```
> dtd
   id main ep
1   1   20  1
2   1   30  2
3   1   12  3
4   1   12  3
5   1   12  3
6   1   15  4
7   1   15  4
8   2   30  1
9   2   12  2
10  2   12  2
11  2   23  3
12  2   23  3
```

So to increment each time there is a change for each `id`.

Any suggestion very welcome.

I came up with this loop but it is quite cumbersome.

```
for(i in 2:nrow(dtd)){
  if(dtd$id[i] == dtd$id[i-1] & dtd$main[i] != dtd$main[i-1] ){
     dtd$ep[i] = dtd$ep[i-1] + 1 
 }
  if(dtd$id[i] == dtd$id[i-1] & dtd$main[i] == dtd$main[i-1] ){
    dtd$ep[i] = dtd$ep[i-1]
  }
}
```

Thanks

the data

```
dtd <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), main = c(20, 
    30, 12, 12, 12, 15, 15, 30, 12, 12, 23, 23), ep = c(1, 2, 3, 
    3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)), .Names = c("id", "main", "ep"), row.names =
    c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ave`:

```
DF$ep <- ave(DF$main, DF$id, FUN = function(x) cumsum(c(1L, diff(x) != 0)))
```

which gives

```
   id main ep
1   1   20  1
2   1   30  2
3   1   12  3
4   1   12  3
5   1   12  3
6   1   15  4
7   1   15  4
8   2   30  1
9   2   12  2
10  2   12  2
11  2   23  3
12  2   23  3
```

I find `cumsum` and `diff` hard to work with and debug, so I would instead use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, ep := rleid(main), by=id]
```

which gives

```
    id main ep
 1:  1   20  1
 2:  1   30  2
 3:  1   12  3
 4:  1   12  3
 5:  1   12  3
 6:  1   15  4
 7:  1   15  4
 8:  2   30  1
 9:  2   12  2
10:  2   12  2
11:  2   23  3
12:  2   23  3
```